# Android Studio Project Run Issue

Tags: android-studio

I have successfully imported Eclipse Project into Android Studio. I have added library projects as modules to that project. Gradle build is also successful but when I run app, it says "Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 23 sec" and error is :
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Any solution to this problem?

I am using Android Studio v1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the project has not been refreshed (Clean and Build) after adding libraries.To resolve it just CLEAN and it will run.